# How do I add text to the about menu page in xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I'm trying to add some copyright text to the about page of my app (Menu > About my_app) currently it just has my app name and version number.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for a file called Credits.rtf it should be next to main.m
There you can edit all our copyright, thanks stuff..

Comment: Thanks! Oddly, there was no Credits.rtf file so I just created one (am using MacRuby). I tried to upvote your answer btw, but it doesn't let me!

Comment: oh yes thats right i did not see your rep. It seems that you havent accepted any answer in any question of yours, try accepting one if i recall accepting your first will take you to 19

Comment: Oh right - I thought upvoting was meant to be the same thing, duh! lol Ok think I've done it now (clicked on the ''tick'') - is that it?

Comment: Yup, only the one who asks can "Tick" selecting the best correct answer, but anyone can support an answer by upvoting it.